# Convert column currency after an importData()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table importing (via importData()) that includes a column full of USD values. I'd like to convert these values to GBP.

I know (presume) that this will be done via =GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDGBP"), but I'm clueless as to how to apply this as the cells are being populated by the importData function. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not too much trouble for you, you can make a sheet that handles the importing of the data only. Then in a separate sheet, just reference the imported cells times the currency conversion rate (given by `GoogleFinance("...")`).

Comment: Yeah, that was (roughly) my backup plan. It'll certainly suffice, I was just hoping for a slightly "neater" solution. Thank you, in any case!

Comment: "Clean" doesn't seem to be achievable here. And of course, there are multiple ways similar to what I gave above.